# Understanding kafka poll and getting entire data

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am  first time using kafka with scala. I am trying to consume data from kafka topic which is already sent by producer. My code is as follows:

```
consumer.poll(5000).asScala.toList
```

I already had 49 records in my kafka topic. When I used this, It brought random records. When I  printed offset and timestamp it started printing offset from 0 to 21. But when I check kafka topic 0 offset timestamp is different. Neither they were last 21 records. Didn't checked all the  record but checked some from last and top. Means it didn't picked actual 0 offset data. Why it is behaving like that?

My consumer configs are as follows:

```
val props = new Properties()
        props.put("group.id", "test")
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
        props.put("group.id", "consumer-group")
```

Secondly, is it possible I can get all the data which is already present from beginning? how can I get it?

Comment: Can you provide your consumer config?

Comment: added. I  just want  to  have data from offset 0 on starting of polling everytime

Comment: if you want to read from beginning you need to change the `group.id` everytime to a new unique group name.

Comment: how i can do that?

Comment: But what I read in official doc is poll consumes data from last offset only.  Then how changing group will fetch data from beginning?

Comment: a new consumer group will read from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

> When I printed offset and timestamp it started printing offset from 0
> to 21. But when I check kafka topic 0 offset timestamp is different

*Offsets are on per-partition basis and not per-topic.* and your topic might have multiple partitions.

You could have checked the timestamp of `0th` offset of `partition 0` and that of the `0th` offset in `partition 1`, which could be different.

> Neither they were last 21 records

The ordering in Kafka is guaranteed per partition i.e. all messages belonging to a topic partition will be in order, however, the order is not guaranteed across multiple partitions of the same topic.

> Secondly, is it possible I can get all the data which is already
> present from beginning? how can I get it?

Yes, it is possible to get all the data from beginning. Check [KafkaConsumer#seekToBeginning()](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/latest/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seekToBeginning-java.util.Collection-) method. An example would be like..

```
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("topic"));
consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment());
```

> But what I read in official doc is poll consumes data from last offset
> only. Then how changing group will fetch data from beginning?

The poll, **by default** will be from *last offset* (`auto.offset.reset`), however, you can change this config to read from *earliest*.

Remember that *earliest* means *beginning*, only if there is no initial consumer offset, not otherwise. If there is a committed offset for that group, then the next message that is read is the one that is after the committed message.

Also, subscriptions are used only when you need to keep of track of what is consumed so that you don't consume them again.

If you would want to always read from beginning, then there is no need for *subscribing* to the topic. You could rather *assign* the topics and seek to beginning. Doing so will not retain any consumer groups and their offset tracking.

```
consumer.assign(consumer.partitionsFor(topic).stream().map(partitionInfo -> new TopicPartition(partitionInfo.topic(), partitionInfo.partition())).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment());
```